Jetpack Compose: `onValueChange()` of `BasicTextField` receives an unexpected updated text
In my app, there is a function to search timetable according to teacher's name. Everything seems good at the beginning, but when I start to test it, there is a problem, let me show you the steps which cause the problem:

Input 'Test' into NoBorderTextField (which is a wrapper of BasicTextField);
Clear the input area by tapping backspace;
Input 'Test' again;

After doing so, 'TestTest' is shown on the input area. (Expected result was 'Test')
I tried to print the value of uiState.searchTeacherName after finishing every steps above, the console is like this:
Test
(Empty)
TestTest

So it seems like uiState.searchTeacherName works well, maybe the bug comes from onValueChange, but I have no idea how to check it and solve it.
Some main codes are as below:
Composable ScheduleScreen function:
fun ScheduleScreen(
    viewModel: ScheduleViewModel
) {
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    ...
    TeacherScheduleBottomSheet(uiState, viewModel)
}

Composable TeacherScheduleBottomSheet function:
fun TeacherScheduleBottomSheet(uiState: ScheduleUiState, viewModel: ScheduleViewModel) {
    ...
    NoBorderTextField(
        value = uiState.searchTeacherName,
        placeholderText = stringResource(R.string.input_teacher_name),
        onValueChange = { viewModel.setSearchTeacherName(it) },
        focusRequester = focusSearchBarRequester
    )
    ...
}

Composable NoBorderTextField function:
fun NoBorderTextField(
    value: String,
    placeholderText: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester? = null,
) {
    ...
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { onValueChange(it) },
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

ScheduleViewModel class:
class ScheduleViewModel @Inject constructor(...) : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(
        ScheduleUiState(...)
    )
    val uiState: StateFlow<ScheduleUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    ...
    fun setSearchTeacherName(value: String) {
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(searchTeacherName = value)
        }
    }
}

Thanks for any help.

Don't use flows (or anything else that is asynchronous) to store a TextField's text while typing: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5 -- Use the BasicTextField overload that takes a state parameter instead of the one with a value parameter. You can get a state object with rememberTextFieldState(). Guidance on how to use the new API: https://proandroiddev.com/basictextfield2-a-textfield-of-dreams-1-2-0103fd7cc0ec -- Please report back if this solves your problem, otherwise [edit] you question with the new code.

@Leviathan, it works, I just change it to BasicTextField2 and still I can use value and onValueChange.
